# Printing out a PHP Array of type object

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 10
            [date_modified] => 2010-07-25 01:51:48
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 16
            [date_modified] => 2010-07-26 14:37:24
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 27
            [date_modified] => 2010-07-26 16:49:17
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 79
            [date_modified] => 2010-08-08 18:53:20
        )

)
```

and what I need to do is print out the user id's comma seperated so:

10, 16, 27, 79

I'm guessing it'd be in a for loop but i'm looking for the most efficient way to do it in PHP

Oh and the Array name is: $mArray

I've tried this:

```
foreach($mArray as $k => $cur)
{
    echo $cur['user_id'];
    echo ',';
}
```

which others have suggested.

However I keep getting this error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in.

I think it's because this array is not a typical array so it requires some different syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Each array element is a (anonymous) object and `user_id` is a property. Use the object property access syntax (`->`) to access it:

```
foreach($mArray as $k => $cur)
{
    echo $cur->user_id;
    echo ',';
}
```

Comment: why `$mArray as $k => $cur` why not `$mArray as $cur` simply

Comment: @Ibrahim Well, no reason. Just copied OPs example.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($mArray as $cur){
   echo $cur->user_id;
}
```

you can do it this way since you are working with objects

Answer (score 2):

Use this if you want to avoid the trailing comma (`,`).

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($array as $obj){
    $ids[] = $obj->user_id;
}

echo join(', ', $ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close...

```
foreach($mArrray as $k => $cur)
{
  echo $cur->user_id.', ';
}
```